# Android ExpandableListView as a Row

Tags: android, layout, row

I'm trying to create a layout, where we have a `RootAdapter`, this is a `ListView`, and a second level `Adapter` class, which handles the rows of the `Listview`.
A single row would look like this:

> `Textview` `Textview` `ExpandableListView`

The problem is that I get the rows, but the `ExpandableListView` only shows the very first item, and only from the group arrays. `GetChildView` is not even called. `GroupView` is called only once, although I checked the given arrays to the adapter are correct.

Can anyone show me a code snippet showing how it could be solved?